# Getting ArrayOutOfBounds and NullPointerException But I don't Know Why

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am testing a program I wrote for an assignment, and right now it's testing at 50% against test cases. I get the following errors when I submit, but I can't figure out why. I tried changing some pieces of code and retesting, but no matter what I do I get the same errors, so I must be completely missing what I should be looking for. Here is the CSV file from which the data is being pulled - 
[CSV Data File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xmAhIbdL00WVBXdDBEWW9fNjA/view). Here are the errors I get:

[image]

Here is my code:

Main class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package csc212hw04;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Michal
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = true;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Car Database");
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array:");
        int size = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
        CarDatabase db1 = new CarDatabase(size);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the input file:");
        String userFile = new String(kb.nextLine());
        db1.readFile(userFile);

        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("Enter make, mpg, weight, all, or quit:");
            String command = kb.nextLine();
            if (command.equals("make")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the make:");
                String make = kb.nextLine();
                db1.displayMake(make);
            } else if (command.equals("mpg")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the mpg range:");
                double mpgLow = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
                double mpgHigh = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
                db1.mpgRange(mpgLow, mpgHigh);
            } else if (command.equals("weight")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the weight range:");
                double weightLow = Double.parseDouble(kb.next());
                double weightHigh = Double.parseDouble(kb.next());
                db1.weightRange(weightLow, weightHigh);
            } else if (command.equals("all")) {
                CarDatabase.displayAll();
            } else if (command.equals("quit")) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

CarDatabase class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package csc212hw04;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
/**
 *
 * @author Michal
 */
public class CarDatabase {
    private static Car[] database;

    public CarDatabase(int s) {
       this.database = new Car[s];
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        boolean full = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            if (database[i] == null) {
                full = false; 
            }
        }

        return full;
    }

    public static void readFile(String f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(f);
        int lineNum = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String csvSplitBy = ",";

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] carData = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            String model = carData[0];
            String make = carData[1];
            double mpg = Double.parseDouble(carData[2]);
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(carData[3]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(carData[4]);
            database[lineNum] = new Car(model, make, mpg, weight, year);
            lineNum++;
        }
    }

    public static void displayMake(String m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            if (database[i].make.equals(m)) {
                database[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void mpgRange(double l, double h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            if (database[i].mpg >= l && database[i].mpg <= h) {
                database[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void weightRange(double l, double h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            if ((database[i].weight >= l) && (database[i].weight <= h)) {
                database[i].toString();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void displayAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            database[i].toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Car class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package csc212hw04;

/**
 *
 * @author Michal
 */
public class Car {
    public String model, make;
    public double mpg;
    public int weight, year;

    public Car(String md, String mk, double umpg, int w, int y) {
        model = md; 
        make = mk;
        mpg = umpg;
        weight = w;
        year = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Model:" + model + " Make:" + make + " mpg:" + " weight:" + " year:" + year;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample from the CSV file if you cannot see it:

[image]

Comment: You should definitely use a debugger here.

Comment: Still pretty new to programming....The class I'm taking hasn't covered the debugger yet, so I'm not too sure how it is used.

Comment: I am not able to open your CSV file, but I assume somewhere there is a formatting error in the file. Which means that somewhere you don't have 6 columns separated by a comma in the file. If you print the line number you might be able to see on which line the error happens.

Comment: I added a sample of what the data in the CSV file looks like.

Comment: You're mixing static variable assignments inside class constructors btw. You're attempting to invoke methods of null references in your array if the file doesn't enter all cars before calling any of the static methods that iterate the array. (ie user enter size 5, file only has two lines, call display, boom)

Comment: In other words you are letting the user dictate how many entries to input, but letting the file dictate how many actually occur. If the user enters less than the file has, your read in will fail. If the file has less than the user enters, your iterations will fail. Choose an input method and stick to it. Read the file twice if you have to in order to decide what the correct length of your array needs to be

Comment: That confused me a bit as well, but according to my assignment: I need to get the size of the array from the user in my main class, then write a constructor in my CarDatabase class that accepts an integer to set the size of the array. The readFile() method is supposed to accept a String (the file name) and use a Scanner to read in all line, create Car objects, and put them in an array.

Comment: I agree with @pinkfloydx33 it's dangerous to have the user provide the length of the array. Also I did a typo. You have 5 columns, not 6. And you still might want to consider printing the line numbers you are reading (so you see on which the error happens) or trying your program with a smaller subset of the CSV file. So you can make sure your code works and then go to the big version (it is possible that it might have a special character or a car with a comma in it's name). By trying a smaller CSV file (e.g. 10 cars)  you can isolate the error possibilities etc. and make your life easier.

Comment: I am now able to get the data extracted and displayed based on the command given........the only thing now is I keep getting a NullPointerException whenever the toString() method is called. The list prints out fine, but always ends with that Exception and the program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting to the End of File and you try to split.  The array then doesn't have any value.  Make sure there is no blank line at the end of your database, or put a check in your readfile to make sure that if the `carData.length == NUMBER OF DATA FIELDS`

#### Update

You also should check to make sure that you don't pass the total number of database entries you have.  So do:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine() && lineNum < database.length) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't my While loop stop when the HasNext() method returns false?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have a blank line at the end of your document it still has a value there even if in a text editor you don't see it.  At the very least it may be the EOF marker

Comment: That's the only thing that would cause that error on that line.  Basically you have to check if when you split the array you actually get an array with 5 elements because you use hard coded indexes.

Comment: This helps! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown in very specific circumstances:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

In your code, you assume that each row in your csv has the same number of fields.

You're also assuming that the size of database array matches the number of cars in your file. Since you don't create your database array entries until you read them from the file - but you pre-initialize the size database array, you could end up reading past the end of your database if the number of records in the CSV is larger than the value you initialize for the database size.